# GUI Test-NetConnection

Tags: powershell

Is it technically possible to output the Test-Netconnection command in a Windows Forms GUI to a textbox?

The ping query with test-connection works wonderfully in the output (see ping_google screenshot).

[Test-Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLZ80.png)
[Test-NetConnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXB3v.png)

If I change the code and want to run the query via test-netconnection, nothing happens when I send an ICMP test (see test-netconnection screenshot). Here is the code I use for this.

```
function trace {
    $Trace_Result = Test-NetConnection $textbox_Search_NW_trace.text -informationlevel "detailed"
    if($Trace_Result) {
        $output_TextBox_NW_trace.Text = ($Trace_Result | Out-String)
    } else {
        $output_TextBox_NW_trace.Text = "Destination is down"
    }    
}
```

I then call the function via the button.

```
$button_Search_NW_trace.Add_Click({trace})
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with how Forms messes with .net waiting for ping responses. I found a workaround in this [github issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11418) which does solve the issue for me:

```
Function trace
{
  $oldSyncContext = $null
  # alter threading get async ping output back from test-netconnection
  try {
    $oldSyncContext = [Threading.SynchronizationContext]::Current
    [Threading.SynchronizationContext]::SetSynchronizationContext($null)
    $output = Test-NetConnection $textbox_Search_NW_trace.text -InformationLevel Detailed | 
      Format-List | 
      Out-String
  } 
  finally {
    if ($null -ne $oldSyncContext) { [Threading.SynchronizationContext]::SetSynchronizationContext($oldSyncContext) }
  }
  # write to textbox
  $textBoxDisplay.Text = $output
}
```

Output looks like so:

[image: screenshot]

This seems to be fixed in newer versions of powershell (7.0.1+)